# SQL Server : joining rows in one table to columns in another and displaying fields multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In a Microsoft SQL Server 2012 database I have two tables. I’ve got a where in the queries to keep it simple.

```
select * from Pricebook_Criteria
where [Part NO] = 'SAW312'


+---------+---------+-----------------------+------------------------+----------+
| Part NO | BrandID | StandardDescriptionID |        Criteria        |  Value   |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+------------------------+----------+
| SAW312  |   15356 |                    82 | Diameter [mm]          | 257      |
| SAW312  |   15356 |                    82 | Height [mm]            | 45       |
| SAW312  |   15356 |                    82 | Thickness [mm]         | 26       |
| SAW312  |   15356 |                    82 | Minimum Thickness [mm] | 24       |
| SAW312  |   15356 |                    82 | Inner Diameter [mm]    | 61       |
| SAW312  |   15356 |                    82 | Weight [kg]            | 6.5      |
| SAW312  |   15356 |                    82 | Number of Holes        | 4        |
| SAW312  |   15356 |                    82 | Class                  | standard |
| SAW312  |   15356 |                    82 | Disc Vent              | standard |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+------------------------+----------+
```

Query:

```
select * 
from Selected_Criteria
where StandardDescriptionID = 82

+-----------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| StandardDescriptionID | SelectedCriteria1 | SelectedCriteria2 |
+-----------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|                    82 | Disc Vent         | Number of Holes   |
+-----------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

What I’m trying to do is to somehow join `Selected_Criteria` and `Pricebook_Criteria` and return the following:

```
+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------+
| Part NO | BrandID | StandardDescriptionID | SelectedCriteria1 | SelectedValue1 | SelectedCriteria2 | SelectedValue2 |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------+
| SAW312  |   15356 |                    82 | Disc Vent         | standard       | Number of Holes   |              4 |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------------+-------------------+----------------+
```

So the idea is for the `StandardDescriptionID = 82` we have picked two criteria to be `SelectedCriteria1` and `SelectedCriteria2`. So based on the data we have in `Pricebook_Criteria` we’d like to display this. What I’m trying to achieve is:

- No duplicated rows. A [Part NO], BrandID, StandardDescriptionID combination is unique, so there should be one line for each
- The 1st and 2nd selected criteria and their respective values in the correct order are displayed as columns

I've gotten pretty close…. But not quite there:

```
select * 
from Pricebook_Criteria 
join selected_criteria as criteria1 ON (pricebook_criteria.StandardDescriptionID = criteria1.StandardDescriptionID AND ((pricebook_criteria.Criteria = criteria1.SelectedCriteria1) OR (pricebook_criteria.Criteria = criteria1.SelectedCriteria2)))
where [part no] = 'SAW312'

+---------+---------+-----------------+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| Part NO | BrandID |    Criteria     |  Value   | StandardDescriptionID | StandardDescriptionID | SelectedCriteria1 | SelectedCriteria2 |
+---------+---------+-----------------+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| SAW312  |   15356 | Number of Holes | 4        |                    82 |                    82 | Disc Vent         | Number of Holes   |
| SAW312  |   15356 | Disc Vent       | standard |                    82 |                    82 | Disc Vent         | Number of Holes   |
+---------+---------+-----------------+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

The problem I have is I’ve duplicated the part for each criteria, I need it to all be on one line like the example above.

Comment: i am sure someone will post the TSQL answer for you, but in short, you want to turn rows to columns for table Pricebook_Criteria, then join on Selected_Criteria. There are multiple ways to do this, most common way is to use PIVOT.

Comment: Have you seen my solution below?  I think it does what you want

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by joining the `selected_criteria` twice - once for each criteria and select the value from the table corresponding to the correct criteria for each column, but...

I'm going to show you another way to do this, which is to use a case expression to selectively choose what data to display in a column - in this case you would compare the SelectedCriteria1 (or 2) with the Criteria:

`SelectedValue1 = case when SelectedCriteria1 = Criteria then Value end`

this will however get you a result like:

```
part no BrandID StandardDescriptionID   SelectedCriteria1   SelectedValue1  SelectedCriteria2   SelectedValue1
SAW312  15356   82                      Disc Vent           NULL            Number of Holes     NULL
SAW312  15356   82                      Disc Vent           standard        Number of Holes     standard
```

which is not quite right. To flatten the rows and remove the null values you can use the `max` function with a `group by` clause, so the final query becomes this:

```
select 
    [part no]
    , BrandID
    , pc.StandardDescriptionID
    , SelectedCriteria1
    , SelectedValue1 = max(case when SelectedCriteria1 = Criteria then Value end)
    , SelectedCriteria2
    , SelectedValue1 = max(case when SelectedCriteria1 = Criteria then Value end)
from Pricebook_Criteria pc
join selected_criteria as c1 
    ON (pc.StandardDescriptionID = c1.StandardDescriptionID 
    AND ((pc.Criteria = c1.SelectedCriteria1) 
    OR (pc.Criteria = c1.SelectedCriteria2))) 
where [part no] = 'SAW312'
group by 
    [part no], BrandID, pc.StandardDescriptionID, 
    SelectedCriteria1, SelectedCriteria2
```

Which will give you:

```
part no BrandID StandardDescriptionID   SelectedCriteria1   SelectedValue1  SelectedCriteria2   SelectedValue1
SAW312  15356   82                      Disc Vent           standard        Number of Holes     standard
```

Using two joins might keep the query tidier.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
select  
  pc1.[part no], pc1.BrandID, pc1.StandardDescriptionID
 ,SelectedCriteria1, pc1.value, SelectedCriteria2, pc2.value
from selected_Criteria sc inner join pricebook_criteria pc1
on (pc1.StandardDescriptionId = sc.StandardDescriptionID 
    and pc1.Criteria = sc.SelectedCriteria1)
inner join pricebook_criteria pc2 
on (pc2.StandardDescriptionId = sc.StandardDescriptionID
    and pc2.Criteria = sc.SelectedCriteria2)
where pc1.[part no] = 'SAW312'
```

Not sure if you also need pc2.[part no] = 'SAW312' or if that is dependent on the StandardDescriptionID